# Boost.Asio: Writing a SSL Server/Client Too many file types

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I want to make a simple SSL server/client couple using Boost.Asio. Before doing that I have read about SSL, certificates, private keys, public keys etc. I used OpenSSL to generate private key (.key) and a certificate (.crt). My certificate is self-signed.

Then, I started digging the Boost.Asio samples. I first tried to write a client. In the sample the verify file was a *.pem file. I had no idea what it was. After searching a little (googling "how to convert crt to pem" etc.) I got that my .crt file is also a .pem file since it starts with `-----BEGIN` and encoded in Base64.

So I have done writing my client and using my .crt file as the argument of `ctx.load_verify_file()`. Is it the appropriate practice?

To test my client, I have started writing a server. Now I have 3 kinds of files, 2 of them that I am not familiar. They are:

- certificate chain file
- private key file (the only one I am familiar)
- temporary dh file

In the example the private key file was also a *.pem file, but my private key file is a *.key file. So I am very confused. Do I need to make any conversion?

So could you explain me:

- What is *.pem file? How can it represent private key as well as verification?
- What is a certificate chain file?
- What is a temporary dh file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PEM File

A [PEM file](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/X.509) (X.509) specifies a format for representing public certificate, certificate chain, public key, etc. in text format.  It can have various extensions (.cert, .key, .pem, etc).  Each item is base64 encoded between a header and footer:

```
-----BEGIN <item type>-----
item data
-----END <item type>-----
```

For instance, the Boost.Asio SSL example's [`server.pem`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.59.0/example/cpp03/ssl/server.pem) file contains:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIB/jCCAWcCCQDlADUqOr8YCTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJB
VTEMMAoGA1UECBMDTlNXMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZTeWRuZXkxDTALBgNVBAoTBGFzaW8w
... more lines ...
WuB94G/gtST9ECVHRKUuBn4xT1rz5DO20h3VSAzTirkSFQPdWunyBbIva0Hsf6pF
287CA1cM106X0Vs4dv2F2u0zSszYfOysAM1pIPcxdyboXA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,9A7CF9C13224C492

w00sJ2/d79LRI+9LRsnQkBZwIo/NbprFtN3SVqcUAtncqowl9BnKZnQ2csnj8KZA
STAL+PZAyJQTiJfJxecCkB8Tu4/apFe2V9/PxUirJzGtJ9FHBAjLgmpK4yWwSCMq
... more lines ...
G+psOVLNgCnFh+z4NO5CB4mVNtrR1NAH6IFhnlrip4YFRk3XPHVlkrxn6fHeEDGE
eVB3XJcgsGnVQCvF5vsymZWZ722xgLPkK8iG3QLayoM4c9RlrKMwwA==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIB7TCCAVYCCQCxKhAUH1ygCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJB
VTEMMAoGA1UECBMDTlNXMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZTeWRuZXkxDTALBgNVBAoTBGFzaW8w
... more lines ...
mQK2WeH6DVQ1r7fWqEq1Lq10qBdobbjDRE9jpezWdGMThbYtle6/8wHUJeq189PR
XwZWyRvnfcI+pqX832yNRh24Ujwuv3wlx3JOVByybCoJc05N1THaHo0Q7j//8HsX
VS/RFHuq3muy47cV9gbsCIw=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Do note that there are other ways to present certificates, such as [PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3369) and [PKCS#12](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/PKCS_12).

---

### Certificate Chain

A certificate chain is a chain of certificates that one steps through from the start to end until a certificate for an explicitly trusted  trusted certificate authority (CA) is found.

- The start of the chain contains an end-user certificate.  This is the certificate issued to the server to which the connection is being made.  A trusted or intermediate CA may have issued this certificate.
- There may be many intermediate certificates between the start and end of the chain.  These are issued to an intermediate CA, and are issued by either a different intermediate CA or a trusted CA.
- The end of the chain contains the root certificate.  This is issued by a trusted CA to itself.  The certificates for trusted CAs are often distributed with web browsers and operating systems.

For example, consider if `example.com` has been issued a certificate by an the `alpha` intermediate CA; `alpha` has been issued a certificate by the `bravo` intermediate CA; and `bravo` has been issued a certificate by the trusted `charlie` CA, whose certificate has been distributed with your web browser package.  With this example, the verification is:

1. Does the end-user `example.com` certificate have `alpha` as its issuer?
2. Does `example.com` certificate verify with `alpha`'s key?
3. Does the intermediate certificate for `alpha` have `bravo` as its issuer?
4. Does `alpha`'s certificate verify with `bravo`'s key?
5. Does the intermediate certificate for `bravo` have `charlie` as its issuer?
6. Does the `bravo` certificate very with `charlie`'s key?
7. Does the root certificate for `charlie` have `charlie` as its issuer?
8. Does the provided `charlie` certificate verify against the `charlie` certificate that has been previously installed on the system as a trusted CA?

---

### DH File

The DH file contains initialization values for the [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), an algorithm for exchanging keys over a public channel while providing [perfect forward secrecy](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Forward_secrecy).  The algorithm enables two parties to generate a shared key while minimizing the change that an observer, who sees the entire exchange, will generate the same key.  The parameter generation can be expensive, so it is often done once in advance and reused for multiple key exchanges.

See the [openssl Diffie Hellman](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman) entry for more details.